# Is there any "man" like command to list structure members?

Tags: c, struct

I think question is clear enough - Is there any "man" like command to list structure members?

For example "FILE" structure, I want to know the member of FILE that contains file descriptor ID.

Comment: Have a peek at `<stdio.h>` ?

Comment: That's I know, just curious to know if there is dictionary like man

Comment: You are not supposed to rely on the implementation of `FILE`. That's why there is no man page for it.

Comment: `man` pages are great for C standard functions, ie things that have a standard definition. The `FILE` struct is implementation defined however, so on each system you worked there could be a different version of the man page seen... or it would be one very long man page listing out all known versions of the `FILE` structure and it would be frequently subject to change

Comment: I'm the man, but I don't take commands. ;-)

Comment: @Shahbaz: Proper engineering requires that there be documentation for the implementation of `FILE`. **Users** of `FILE` do not need to know its internal details, but **somebody** must implement it, and usually multiple people have to maintain it. So somewhere there should exist documentation for the internal operations of each implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, of course, that could be for example inside the glibc repository. But it wouldn't be available for the end-user as _any “man” like command to ..._ would imply.

Comment: fopen returns pointer of type FILE. Any alternative to fopen available from C standard library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FILE` is opaque. The members are none of your business unless you're hacking the C library.

The `fileno` function returns the file descriptor for a given `FILE *`.

For structures that aren't meant to be opaque, you normally find the members you're allowed to access listed in the man page for the function that returns the structure, for example `struct stat` is documented in **stat**(2)

The POSIX man page set includes man pages for header files (for example **stat.h**(0P)) and struct members are listed there.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not believe such a command is exist.

And structures such as `FILE` suppose to be opaque types, you does not need to know their internal details in order to use them.